# JQuery hide Class if other class is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question already have asked before and i also tried the answer and it almost worked for me but there is one issue which i can't able to sort i tried plenty of ways but all in wain. 
This is the div i want to hide

```
    <div class="price-box" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

       <p class="price"><span class="special-price" style="display: none;">
        <span class="amount">$43.50</span>
        </span>
       </p>
    </div>
```

when this div is not empty

```
<div class="single_variation"><span class="price"><span class="amount">$43.50</span></span></div>
```

This is what i implement

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    if( jQuery('.single_variation').is(':empty') ){
        alert('hi');
        jQuery('.price-box').show();
    }

  });
```

and also

```
if($('.price').length) {
    $('.price-box').hide();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `:empty` only checks for empty backgrounds ?

Comment: Why do you have `meta` and `link` tags in the body?

Comment: that was my mistake i have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

`:empty` select elements that have no children.

What you need to check is "`:visible`" :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    if($('.single_variation').is(':visible') ){
      alert('hi');
      $('.special-price').hide();
    }

});
```

Also I replaced show by hide.

Edit :
What is this ?

```
if($('.category').length){
  $('.filter').hide();
}
```

There is no class like category or filter in your example. Not useful in your question !

Comment: actually i by default make it display none

Comment: You changed your question but it's still unclear. Please reformulate what you need. Visible or empty ? Not the same thing.

Comment: sorry my mistake please check now

Comment: Please open this [link](http://clothing.inkgility.com/product/american-apparel-f497-unisex-flex-fleece-zip-hoodie/) then it'll be clear. i want to hide the price which is showing above if the price below is visible

Comment: do you understand @FLX?